# How to get enable state of chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Google Chrome has changed its mechanism for silently installing extensions. External extension deployment options on Windows will be disabled by default since Chrome 25, User need to open "Extension Settings" page to enable extensions manually.

Can I have some way to enable an extension programmatically or detect the enable state of an extension?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [chrome.management](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) API will let you know whether an extension is enabled or disabled. Of course, if your own extension is able to call this method, then you already know it's enabled.

Enterprises can install extensions by policy, but a consumer product can't and shouldn't abuse enterprise policy simply to install silently.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be long past useful, but for anyone else wondering how to accomplish this, here's a rundown (as of Chrome 45, Windows edition):

1. The state is stored in Google Chrome's Secure Preferences file. This is a JSON format file stored in %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\ProfileFolder.
   Profile folder may be "Profile 1", or a user specific folder, of "Default" if no users are setup. Check your directory to make sure.
2. The extension state is stored in:
   extensions: settings: (Extension ID) : State node. State is 0 for disabled, 1 for enabled.
   EG:
   { "extensions" : { "settings" : { "ahfgeienlihckogmohjhadlkjgocpleb" : "state" : 1 } } }
3. Word of warning, don't mess with this file. Use it for reading purposes only, there are hashes of the preferences settings setup to prevent unauthorized non-user modification.